# User defined Ordering using Stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to the Java 8 Stream API.I have below requirement My ordering rule is : "A","C","D","B"
   I have result which having Object containing 8-9 elements and duplicate elements also.

Below is my code :

```
public class A
{
private String name;
    public A()
    {
    }
    public A(String name )
    {
     this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [name=" + name + "]";
    }
```

I have another class :

```
public class B
{
   enum TypeEnum{
    A("A"),
    C("C"),
    D("D"),
   B("B");

    private String s;

    private TypeEnum(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

public static void main(String agrs[] )
   {

   Collection<A> stringCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    stringCollection.add(new A("A"));
    stringCollection.add(new A("D"));
    stringCollection.add(new A("D"));
    stringCollection.add(new A("C"));
    stringCollection.add(new A("D"));
    stringCollection.add(new A("B"));
    stringCollection.add(new A("A"));
    stringCollection.add(new A("A"));

    Predicate<A> aPredicate = a -> a.getName() == TypeEnum.A.name();
    Predicate<A> cPredicate =  a -> a.getName()== TypeEnum.C.name();
    Predicate<A> dPredicate =  a -> a.getName()== TypeEnum.D.name();
    Predicate<A> bPredicate =  a -> a.getName()== TypeEnum.B.name();

    Predicate<A> fullPredicate = aPredicate.and(cPredicate)
            .and(dPredicate).and(bPredicate);

    List<A> list= stringCollection.stream().filter(fullPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Here the output should be A,A,A,C,D,D,D,B

I want to order the element as per the specified rule as per the mention in above using Stream java 8 API. Class A is a object which is used in class B to put the value in the list which is type of Class A. The final result should be ordered as per the defined ordering rule. It would be great and thankful if anybody face the same issue and having solution for the same.

Comment: Look for `Comparator` there are many examples on SO

Comment: And then pls show us what you just tried.

Comment: And the sorting rule is???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  Sorting rule : "A","C","D","B"

Comment: but that is not a sorting rule, that is a desired output....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ its not as restrict with the sorting rule but the order should be as i mentioned "A","C","D","B" .

Comment: I think this is too close to other sorting questions... check Documentation on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/4237/sort-using-stream#t=20170329155658911898

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ thanks for the update i modified the code and i combined multiple predicate rule as per the criteria, i get the result with an empty list. Please refer the code and suggest if any approach need to follow.

Comment: @Jérôme Hi i modified the code as per the expected result and i  also combined the predicate conditions and finally applied predicate to stream but i am getting an empty list please suggest if i missed anything.

Comment: You are combining all `Predicate`s so your `A` object has to be from `TypeEnum` `A` and `B` and `C` and `D`. Since this is not the case you get a empty list. **And please compare two `String`s with `equals`!!!**

Answer (score 2):

You can simply sort by a given list’s position:

```
List<String> order = Arrays.asList("A", "C", "D", "B");
List<A> result = collection.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> order.indexOf(a.getName())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will put names not specified in the list at the front. You move them to the end instead, by using the comparator `Comparator.comparingInt(a -> order.indexOf(a.getName())+Integer.MIN_VALUE)`.

Due to the repeated use of `indexOf`, this will not scale well for a larger `order` list.

An alternative is a bucket sort variant:

```
Map<String, List<A>> m = collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getName));
List<A> result = Stream.of("A", "C", "D", "B")
    .flatMap(s -> m.getOrDefault(s, Collections.emptyList()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here, names not specified won’t show up in the result at all. It will have a better time complexity, but might consume more memory temporarily.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and quick reply.

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise, you may elaborate what is still missing.

Comment: @ Holger @Jérôme@ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Hi instead of Stream.of("A", "C", "D", "B") i want to use Enum for that below changes i made in the code but i wont get the String with format like "A","C","D","B"

Comment: @ Holger @Jérôme@ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Hi instead of Stream.of("A", "C", "D", "B") i want to use Enum for that below changes i made in the code but i wont get the String with format like "A","C","D","B".            public enum TypeEnum{  A("A"),C("C"),D("D"), B("B");
     private String value; private TypeEnum(String value) { this.value= value;} // setter getter public static String getString(){LinkedList<String> ls= new LinkedList<>(); for(TypeEnum t : TypeEnum.values()){ ls.add(t.getValue());}String str = ls.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));return str;} suggeston the same

Comment: Then, what’s the question? Your `ls.stream()` produces a stream equivalent to `Stream.of("A", "C", "D", "B")` which you can use exactly the same if your task is still the same as in the question (as I don’t know the purpose of `collect(Collectors.joining(","))`).But there’s no reason for a `List` at all (not to speak of a `LinkedList`); you could just use `EnumSet.allOf(TypeEnum.class).stream() .map(Enum::name)` (which also works with `enum TypeEnum { A, C, D, B }` without the redundant string,or use `EnumSet.allOf(TypeEnum.class).stream().map(TypeEnum::getValue)` if you insist on `getValue()`

Comment: instead of hard coding list i need to pass enum list so previously i iterate the enum values and add in the list and then passing in the Stream.of() method. By using EnumSet.allOf(TypeEnum.class).stream() .map(Enum::name) this approach it works thanks for your help and quick response.